# 2D BHZ tight binding model for Quantum spin Hall insulator

Tags: topology, topological-insulators, tight-binding

I am currently reading this article : https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0611341 and want to derive the k-space tight binding model of 2D BHZ.

The tight binding model is written as
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{i,\sigma,\alpha} \epsilon_{\alpha} c^{\dagger}_{i,\alpha,\sigma} c_{i,\alpha,\sigma} - \sum_{i,a,\sigma,\alpha,\beta}t_{a,\sigma,\alpha,\beta}c^{\dagger}_{i+a,\alpha,\sigma}c_{i,\beta,\sigma}
\end{equation}
where $i$ denotes the 2D lattice point, $\sigma = +,-$ denotes the spin index, $\alpha,\beta=s,p$ denote the orbital index and $a = \pm\hat{x},\pm \hat{y}$ denote the nearest neighbor hopping direction.

The hopping is given by
\begin{equation}
t_{a,\sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
    t_{ss} & t_{sp}e^{i \sigma \theta_{a}} \\
    t_{sp}e^{-i\sigma \theta_{a}} & -t_{pp}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\theta_{a}$ is the angle between $a$ and $x$-axis. This means that $\theta_{\hat{x}} = 0$, $\theta_{\hat{y}} = 0.5\pi$, $\theta_{-\hat{x}} = \pi$ and $\theta_{-\hat{y}} = 1.5\pi$.

My question is that, in the article it seems that the Hamiltonian is not even a Hermitian matrix. The following is my reasoning.

Consider the hopping terms denoting a $s \uparrow$ orbital hopping to $p \uparrow$ from site $i$ to site $i+\hat{x}$, then the corresponding term in the tight binding model is 
\begin{equation}
{\rm a\ hopping\ parameter\ }\cdot c^{\dagger}_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow} c_{i,s,\uparrow}.
\end{equation}
To determine this hopping parameter, we should choose to use the entry $t_{sp}e^{-i\sigma \theta_{a}}$. Therefore the hopping term is given by
\begin{equation}
t_{sp}e^{-i \cdot (+1) \cdot (\theta_{\hat{x}})}c^{\dagger}_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow} c_{i,s,\uparrow} = t_{sp} c^{\dagger}_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow} c_{i,s,\uparrow}
\end{equation}

**Now, lets consider the hopping from $p,\uparrow$ at $i+\hat{x}$ to $s,\uparrow$ at $i$**, this term should look like
\begin{equation}
{\rm a\ hopping\ parameter\ }\cdot c^{\dagger}_{i,s,\uparrow} c_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow}.
\end{equation}
Because this is a hopping from $p$ to $s$ we should choose to use the entry $t_{sp}e^{i \sigma \theta_{a}}$, which leads to 
\begin{equation}
t_{sp}e^{i \cdot (+1) \cdot \theta_{-\hat{x}}} \cdot c^{\dagger}_{i,s,\uparrow} c_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow} = t_{sp}e^{i \cdot (+1) \cdot \pi} \cdot c^{\dagger}_{i,s,\uparrow} c_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow} = -t_{sp}c^{\dagger}_{i,s,\uparrow} c_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow}
\end{equation}
**Note that I use $\theta_{-\hat{x}}$ rather than $\theta_{\hat{x}}$ in this expression which follows from the definition of the hopping matrix $t_{a,\sigma}$ and the angle $\theta_{a}$**. This is because in this case the hopping is actually pointing at $-\hat{x}$ but not $\hat{x}$.

However, for a Hamiltonian to be a Hermitian, we need to require 
\begin{equation}
(t_{sp} c^{\dagger}_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow} c_{i,s,\uparrow})^{\dagger} = -t_{sp}c^{\dagger}_{i,s,\uparrow} c_{i+\hat{x},p,\uparrow}.
\end{equation}
As we can easily calculate, the above equation requires $t_{sp} = 0$ provided that $t_{sp} \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, there is no reason that $t_{sp}$ should be zero. Therefore I am suspecting that the hopping matrix should be modified as
\begin{equation}
t_{a,\sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
    t_{ss} & t_{sp}e^{i \sigma \theta_{a}} \\
    -t_{sp}e^{-i\sigma \theta_{a}} & -t_{pp}
\end{bmatrix}\ {\rm or\ } t_{a,\sigma} = \begin{bmatrix}
    t_{ss} & -t_{sp}e^{i \sigma \theta_{a}} \\
    t_{sp}e^{-i\sigma \theta_{a}} & -t_{pp}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

By doing this, the non-Hermitian problem will be resolved.

I am wondering did some of you actually carry out the Bloch transformation of the 2D BHZ model in this article and arrive the same conclusion as me? If not, could some of you tell me how to modify my deduction? In my opinion what is written in the article can not be Hermitian.

I will be grateful for any suggestion! Thanks!